# Where do I find large face datasets?

Tags: dataset, image-processing

Are there any large, freely available (but not necessarily labeled) face datasets out there?

The ones I have seen usually range in the hundreds, but for unsupervised feature learning it would be desirable to have thousands if not tens or hundreds of thousands of images.

If the answer is no, what would be a good way of obtaining such a dataset? If the answer is yes, where do I find them and what have they been used for?

Comment: What about small faces ;-)

Comment: also look at FERET dataset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can handle unconstrained imaging conditions you should perhaps look at [LFW](http://vis-www.cs.umass.edu/lfw/) and [PubFig](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/databases/pubfig/).

If you need controlled imaging conditions you should perhaps look at [MultiPIE](http://www.multipie.org/).